# how to use regex to find repeated phrases?

Tags: regex, repeat

I'm editing an epub made by some kids as school assignement. In this file there's often multiple copy/paste errors. So i've exported the whole thing to a xhtml file and, using SublimeText (if this matters), i'd need to find if the last 4 or 5 words before the `</p>` tag are already present in the same line (or even better, after the related `<p>` tag).

As example, this is what i find very often:

```
<p>This is a whole paragraph that shouldn't contain any repetition. that shouldn't contain any repetition.</p>
```

There's some examples here and in the web about finding repetitions, but they always looks forward, while i need to find the repetition backward (or at least it seems so to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that the tags `<p>` aren't there since in that case the statement doesn't finish with a repetition.

So, if the text is just:

> This is a whole paragraph that shouldn't contain any repetition. that shouldn't contain any repetition.

Then you could use somethine like this:

```
(.+)\1
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA7oX8/1)**

**Update**: as **[revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo)** pointed in his comment you can leverage positive lookahead to match the pattern

```
(.+)\1(?=<\/p>)
```

Comment: The tags are exactly where they are in the example. I need to find the repetitions inside the tags (or at least, in the same line and before the </p> tag).

Comment: Then go with `(.+)\1(?=<\/p>)` @FabioCalzolari

Comment: @revo was testing that. Updated the answer with your comment, thanks.

Comment: Also if there is a chance that new-line characters may exist, I would consider removing all new-lines within a `p` tag before applying the main RegEx `\R(?=(?:(?!<p>).)*<\/p>)`